# Django how to access an abstract Base model local variables

Tags: python, django, abstract-class

I have defined this abstract base model as below:

```
class ActivityAbstractBaseModel(models.Model):
    POOR = 'PR'
    FAIR = 'FA'
    MEDIOCRE = 'ME'
    GOOD_ENOUGH = 'GE'
    GOOD = 'GO'
    VERY_GOOD = 'VG'
    EXCELLENT = 'EX'

    STATE = [
        (POOR, 'Poor'),
        (FAIR, 'Fair'),
        (MEDIOCRE,'Mediocre' ),
        (GOOD_ENOUGH, 'Good Enough' ),
        (GOOD, 'Good'),
        (VERY_GOOD, 'Very Good'),
        (EXCELLENT, 'Excellent'),
    ]

    speaking = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=STATE, default=GOOD)
```

I then inherit this abstract model as below and added the new field `writing`

```
class Fluency(ActivityAbstractBaseModel):
    writing = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=STATE, default=GOOD)
```

Now, this new field `writing` is trying to access the variable `GOOD` and `STATE` that was created in the abstract class but I am having the `NameError` exception. Is there a way to get these variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your class will inherit those class variables but the code you cannot directly refer them where you define your class (because they don't exist in that scope). Instead you can refer to them as `ActivityAbstractBaseModel.GOOD`, etc. inside your class declaration.

```
class Fluency(ActivityAbstractBaseModel):
    writing = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=ActivityAbstractBaseModel.STATE, default=ActivityAbstractBaseModel.GOOD)

print(Fluency.GOOD) # This works properly
```

Comment: It is strange because, I can access `speaking` from the abstract base model and modify it and even remove it using `speaking=None`. Is it that Django exposes fields and not the other variables?

Comment: @EyongKevinEnowanyo it's not Django related. Just try it with normal classes, this doesn't work. You can set `speaking` but that's just you redefining it and not referring it (You might be talking about referring it in methods that would work for other variables too e.g. `self.GOOD` would work properly in methods)